# Best way to login with API and save token in Android

Tags: android, api

I am developing a messaging and social networking application on Android.

Current steps:

1. The user enters his username and password when entering the application.
2. The username and password entered are sent to the server and validation is performed.
3. The server responds by sending a token to the user and storing it in the database. (Both client and server store same tokens)
4. In each request - the user sends this token to the server and is validated by it.

The question is:
Is this a safe and secure method? If not, what solution do you suggest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming you are used rest API for server communication. To make your API request more secure you can use JWT token in the header which needs to implement both app and server-side.